# uinavigationcontroller after many push and pop not working

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My UINavigationController is not more working after many push and pop. I have tested the transition´s operations and the content of the stack of my UINavigationController. The ViewControllers are nice pushed and popped. But after many times i tried to push a ViewController.

This one is added to the stack but it is view is not showing, and my app is blocked. I have tried to debug but i can not become an Exception.

I think the problem is that the view of the new pushed ViewController is not be showing.

Anyone has an idea what kind of mistake it can be achieved?

```
ImpressumController* impressumVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImpressumController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:impressumVC animated:YES];
NSLog(@"navigation viewcontrollers %@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
```

Popping code.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Without seeing any code it isn't possible to help with this. You need to show some code. Like the code used for transitions.

Comment: ImpressumController* impressumVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImpressumController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:impressumVC animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"navigation viewcontrollers %@",self.navigationController.viewControllers );

Comment: Poppen: I used back button :

Comment: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: It's much nicer to read if you put code into the question by editing it not in the comments.

Comment: and i don´t use barbutton , i mean with poppen i used swiping or backbutton

Comment: Do you see anything in the log when the view goes black? Have you tried using the view debugger?

Comment: Yes i see the stack. It is updated. I mean when i pop then the pushed VC is  deleted from Stack

Comment: And after many push and pop, i achieved a push operation , the stack is updated but the transition not (the view of the pushed VC is not appeared). And the app is blocked

Comment: If you're using a storyboard file should you not be using segues for transitions?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your view controller is being deallocated and your memory usage is not growing. Just override `- (void)dealloc` function and put there a break point to check if it is being reached.

Comment: I have implemented what you have suggested. It works well. I think the problem is with swiping. I implemented this 2 lines in my rootViewController of the navigationController :

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES; self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;

Comment: Because i don´t use navigationBar.